# Who were the three lawmakers who voted against decriminalising domestic violence in Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, crime

In [Russian parliament votes 380-3 to decriminalise domestic violence](http://www.smh.com.au/lifestyle/news-and-views/news-features/russian-parliament-votes-3803-to-decriminalise-domestic-violence-20170128-gu0q86.html), it's said that there was a 380 to 3 vote in favour of a bill to decriminalise domestic violence under certain circumstances.

Who were the three who voted against it?

I looked up Wikipedia, and it [mentioned the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_Russia#Decriminalization_of_domestic_violence), but not who opposed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [official parliament statistics](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fvote.duma.gov.ru%2Fvote%2F97268), these three MPs opposed the bill in its third (and final) reading:

- Nikolay Yezersky
- Yury Sinelshchikov
- Sergey Shargunov

All three belong to the Communist Party of Russia, which [consistently opposed the bill](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-38767873). In fact, only one Communist MP voted in favor of the bill, while the remaining 38 party members didn't vote at all (didn't abstain, mind you - just didn't show up).